# Destroy MDI child window in VC++ 6

Tags: c++

I've got a child window, declared in CMainFrame:

```
CMDIChildWnd pMyMDI = new CMDIChildWnd;
pMyMDI->Create(NULL, ..., ..., ..., this);

.... some codes....

if (pMyMDI != NULL)
{
   pMyMDI->DestroyWindow();
   pMyMDI = NULL
}
```

It always has error when I'm trying to destroy the the window with a message something like "Invalid handle". How should I get the handle and safely destroy this window?

Comment: I'm sure you can transcribe the error message precisely. Exactly what does it say.

Comment: "Unhandled Exception in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation". It appears the very first time the code executed. At line "DestroyWindows()"

Comment: Most likely, the window has already been destroyed. We can't tell because we can't see `..... some codes ....`

Comment: but... pMyMDI != NULL was checked? Is there any other way to check before running the "DestroyWindow()"?

Comment: That's to be expected. The framework deletes the object when the window is closed, but it won't set your reference to `NULL`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can even make it simplier. In side my CMainFrame.h, I put a line: "CMDChildWnd pMyMDI;" Inside my CMainFrame.cpp, I put 2 lines: "if (pMDIChild != NULL)  pMyMDI->DestroyWindow();" The exception generates right when it sees thte line "DestroyWindows"

Comment: Knowing what code is there is only part of it. We need to know when it runs. You could give us a simple program that we can compile and run.

Comment: This line of code 'pMyMDI->Create(NULL, ..., ..., ..., this);', has this window been created successfully and appeared properly on the screen ?

Comment: These lines executed when a menu bar in main frame is clicked. No other codes above it. : if (pMyMDI != NULL)
{
   pMyMDI->DestroyWindow();
   pMyMDI = NULL
}

Comment: Here's how to duplicate: create an MFC MDI app with VC++6. Inside CMainFrame.h, declare CMDIChildWnd pMyMDI; Return to CMainFrame, on "AboutDlg" click event, put these codes in: if (pMyMDI != NULL) { pMyMDI->DestroyWindow(); pMyMDI = NULL }